# Browser and openSSL return different certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I'm trying to debug my first attempt at using SSL Pinning in an app I'm developing.

I use a shared hosting service on which I have a few domains active.  One of the domains is going to act as an API endpoint.  I want to make use of SSL Pinning to improve security.

I asked my hosting provider to install the certificate, key and CA Bundle.  That seemed to go OK, because when I browse the site using any web browser, the certificate detail matches what I expect to see.

However when I try to connect using my app, it fails because the certs don’t match.  I’m still figuring out how to debug this part better and see what the app is matching on … but that is for another thread

As part of my troubleshooting I’ve run

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts
```

which is sending back a wildcard certificate which is tied to the service provider - I expected to see my certificate that I see in the browser

So my questions are:

- Is my expectation right that the certificate shown in the browser should match what openssl returns?
- if not, can someone explain to me why the difference?

My development environment is MAC OS/X and the installed version of openssl is OpenSSL 0.9.8zf 19 Mar 2015.  The hosting provider uses light speed (not sure of their OS).  I use a standard apache/PHP setup for local development

Comment: With regard to the openssl command line, [read this](https://major.io/2012/02/07/using-openssls-s_client-command-with-web-servers-using-server-name-indication-sni/). You need to account for SNI in your program.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Thanks - SNI eventually led me to finding the (multiple) challenges I had, but now all is working!